# CMOS Inverter Transistor Sizing Wording

Tags: transistors, inverter, cmos

"Assume that both the gate lengths as well as W_n for the 180 nm technology in the table can have dimensions down to 180 nm."

I'm simply wondering here what they're referring to with the "dimensions down to 180nm"? Are they stating that the gate lengths and W_n are fixed at 180nm? Or are they stating that it's possible to change all of those - and if so, then what is the 180nm technology specifically referring to besides the (given to us) parameters of \$\mu C_o, V_t,\$ etc?

And for additional context, this is for an unskewed CMOS inverter.

Comment: The statement means that the minimum L & W is 180nm. You cannot use anything lower than it.